# Listen to a callback from an API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

How do I receive callbacks in the form of a JSON object to a particular page on my website? These callbacks are being made from a third-party API to report the status of my communication with that API.

I thought of using node.js' http.server.listen, but I can't find a suitable example for me to work with.

I am using Meteor.js.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like meteor has ajax functionality. If the API returns a JSON object, you should just be able to access it via the data parameter in a callback function you pass to one of meteor's http methods.

See the meteor http documentation [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http).

Comment: I understand. But I have to call the API synchronously, which means I don't have a callback function to meteor's http.call method. Could you explain how to do this when calling the API in synchronous mode?

Comment: May I ask why you have to call it synchronously?